# How to call jquery method in different page event like pageload, ispostback, page refresh, onsubmit

Tags: jquery, events

In my master page I am calling the jquery method on pageload event. It will do some truncation operation in a SharePoint page. The problem is, if I have add new item to the SharePoint form and if I submit the form, my page got postback (refreshed) so the jquery method not called.

- After submiting the form, if I reload the page its working properly.

Is there any way to call the jquery method in different event?
How to resolvet the issue.

The below jquery only I am using in my page.  [Jquery](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Truncate-text-in-list-view-and-add-mouseover-preview.aspx)

Comment: If your page got postback(refreshed), jQuery document ready event **must** fire. Check for javascript errors on postback.

Comment: Can you post some code to help illustrate your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a partial refresh of the page, like in UpdatePanel, jQuery(document).ready(), or jQuery(window).load() don't fire. You must find some event that fires. You can start to lab with [PageRequestManager. It helped me in my UpdatePanel](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/javascript-load-callback-for-updatepanel/).

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(doSomethingGreat);
```